# Is `cp --no-clobber` vulnerable to race condition?

Tags: linux, shell, files, security, cp

The man page for [`cp(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) says

> `--no-clobber` do not overwrite an existing file

However, wouldn't the following scenario be possible?

1. `cp` checks the file existence, let's assume the file doesn't exist (yet)
2. Some other process writes to the same path, so now there is data written to the previously not existing file
3. Since `cp` isn't aware of the now existing file, it overwrites the data

Is `cp --no-clobber` vulnerable to this race condition? And if not, how does `cp` avoid the situation above?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`cp` isn’t vulnerable to this race condition. When `--no-clobber` is set, it checks whether the destination already exists; if it determines it doesn’t, and it should therefore proceed with the copy, it remembers that it’s supposed to copy to a new file. When the time comes to open the destination file, [it opens it with flags which enforce its creation](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/copy.c#n1157), [`O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html); the operating system then checks that the file doesn’t exist *while opening it*, and fails (`EEXIST`) if it does.

Comment: `O_EXCL` is obvious enough that one might assume other implementations do the same. Though I did start thinking about NFS, and if there were some issues with `O_EXCL` with it.

Comment: @ilkkachu on Linux, there are, with NFSv2 or pre-2.6 kernels.

Comment: I didn’t want to make any claims regarding potential race conditions other than the specific one being discussed here ;-). Except with block devices on Linux, `O_EXCL` is only meaningful when used with `O_CREAT`, so as you suspect it can’t be used for `--update` (to ensure that the destination isn’t update after its timestamp is checked). Avoiding races for `--update` would require more complex file locking schemes...

Comment: It's interesting that `cp` would check the existence itself instead of simply opening with those flags.

Comment: @JoL I don't have any source or support for this beyond my gut feeling, but I'd bet any amount of money that the original version of cp didn't use O_EXCL and therefore did have a race condition, which was later patched out by changing the open() call to use O_EXCL, and the original now-superfluous check was just never removed.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield I don't have any source either, but I think it's not superfluous. It's probably still needed for `--interactive`. Though, I imagine it could probably be reworked to ask after getting a `EEXIST` error instead of doing the check, but the change is probably not worth it.

Comment: A similar issue exists for `ksh88` which doesn't use `O_EXCL` when `noclobber` (`-C`) is set and therefore has a race condition.  `ksh88` is still the standard shell in AIX.

Comment: Does `cp --no-clobber` exit nonzero if it hits this EEXIST case?